# Sync mongo collection from one database to other

Tags: mongodb, view

I have 2 mongo database on the same cluster. One of the database is primary for the application while the other is backup database to which periodic sync is done from primary database. So far both the databases used to have only collections and we are using a service provider's utility to sync the databases.
However we have recently created some views and the provider does not have utility for syncing of views. I am new to mongodb and trying to see if there is a way to sync the view definitions across databases. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: MongoDB views are non-materialized, so they essentially just consist of a pipeline definition.  Are you looking to sync changes to the definition of the view?

Comment: yes basically the view definition be synced. Editing the original question as well

Comment: Mongodump/mongorestore should be able to handle that, but I've never tried

Comment: I need to do it programmatically (preferably java)

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the Java driver, you should be able to run the listCollections command filtered to show views, and then create those views in the other server.